# Python: verify that each array item is in array of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to verify that each array item is in array of dictionaries

```
verify_obj = {5492: [2, 3]}
sc = [{'key': 2, 'key_2': 4}, {'key': 4, 'key_2': 5}, {'key': 5, 'key_2': 7}, {'key': 6, 'key_2': 10}]
for k, v in verify_obj.items():
    if all(i for i in v) != any(j['key1'] for j in sc):
        print('test fail')
```

Expect printing of `test fail` in console that `3` of array `[2, 3]` is not in   `sc` object, but message was not printed.
What's going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only change needed was your evaluation: `if all(i for i in v) != any(j['key'] for j in sc)`.

```
verify_obj = {5492: [2, 3]}
sc = [{'key': 2}, {'key': 4}, {'key': 5}, {'key': 10}]
for k, v in verify_obj.items():
    if not all([True if x in [values for dict_i in sc for values in dict_i.values()] else False for x in v]):
        print('test fail')
```

`any()` and `all()` checks for `if el`, i.e. is the current element `True`? What you are checking is this: `True != True` which is `False`.

For example, this will print "test fail" for your example:

`if all(i for i in v) == any(j['key'] for j in sc)`

but that is only because you have no `False` values in the `any()` or `all()` since no integer is `False` when evaluating it against a `bool`.

Instead, check if any of the values in `verify_obj` exists in any dictionary of `sc`.

All/any function ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any

Comment: change `verify_obj` to `{5492: [2, 4]}` and result also will be `test failed`, but expect that not failed due to `2` and `4` is in `sc` object

Comment: Correct, try printing `v` and the list comprehension and see what happens. There should be enough clues there to what is going on.

Comment: by your answer `test fail` will be always printed due to `key` is not an array, but an integer value, i'm trying to check if each array value, i.e. `2`, `3` has in `sc` array, just `key` in `sc` has value `2` and `key` in `sc` has value `3`, `sc` could have many `key` values

Comment: I meant `print(v)`. If you do it just before you evaluation you will see that it checks if `[x,y]` is in `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. The list `[x,y]` is not a member of `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, as such you have to iterate over `[x,y]` and if any element is not in `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` print test fail.

Comment: i know, that `v` is array of `[2, 3]`, so.... i need to verify, if each item of this array is in array of dictionaries...how to do that ? so i tried `all(i for i in v)`

Comment: `all(i for i in v)` checks if all values in v, e.g. `2` and `3`, are `True` (or in this case, not `False`). What you need is (1) select the individual values in `v` and then (2) compare the value `v` against a list containing ALL values in `sc` for all keys.
To get the values of all of the dicts in `sc` you can use the code I posted in the evaluation e.g. `[value for dict_i in sc for value in a.values()]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156849/discussion-between---and-00sdf0).

Answer (score 2):

Use `any()` with the condition checking if any value in `verify_obj`'s list is not in `sc`. `sub` contains the list which is in `verify_obj`. `sup` is a list of the values in `sc`.

```
verify_obj = {5492: [2, 3]}
sc = [{'key': 2}, {'key': 4}, {'key': 5}, {'key': 10}]

sub = next(iter(verify_obj.values()))
sup = [v for d in sc for k, v in d.items() if k == "key"]

if any(v not in sup for v in sub):
    print("test fail")
```

`issubset()` can also accomplish this. To make use of it, the list in `verify_obj` has to be converted to a set. The argument used for the function is a set of the values in `sc`.

```
verify_obj = {5492: [2, 3]}
sc = [{'key': 2}, {'key': 4}, {'key': 5}, {'key': 10}]

s = set(next(iter(verify_obj.values())))

if not s.issubset(v for d in sc for k, v in d.items() if k == "key"):
    print("test fail")
```

Comment: need to verify only for dictionary value by key with name `key`, not all values, dictionary could contain many keys

Comment: @ВладДавидченко I've update my answer to check the key name.

Comment: thx, used solution with list like `if any(k not in [j['key'] for j in sc] for k in v):print('test failed')`